# Going crazy getElementsByTagName not working on PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, encoding, domdocument

I have a very simple code like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($data);
libxml_clear_errors();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    // do something here
}
```

The variable $data contains HTML from a external URL. Ok, if i test this code using my local webserver using PHP 5.3.6 it works and returns ALL img tags in that page, but same code running on another server with PHP 5.3.3 DOESN'T WORK! It doesn't return all img tags from the SAME $data value... it only returns the first 13 images.

I suspect that this has something to do with encoding, may be that some characters in $data have a bad encoding or something, but i don't know how to solve it. There is a known bug on PHP 5.3.3 related to this?

Comment: Are you using different libxml versions on each install? What libxml errors do you get? Does using `DOMXPath` with query `//img` also not show anything?

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you check out the comments on the php docs page,
looks like there's some useful advice on the DOMDocument usage:
http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

And before you ask for (eventually) known bugs on stackoverflow,
you might want to look for it on https://bugs.php.net/

Edit:

I think I've found the bug related to that behavior:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60762

Even though it's flagged 5.4.0 RC 5 I couldn't replicate
the behavior mentioned.
Probably an issue with the HTML data (as you mentioned).

Comment: There isn't any useful advice into the comments section of that page. I've readed it all... As i've wrote on my post the same code is working on php 5.3.6... are you talking about libxml2 issues in that comments?

Comment: I meant the comment by "Philip N" about getElementsByTagName returning a dynamic list - could be an issue iterating over it with foreach in PHP 5.3.3 - I'm sorry, but I currently can't replicate your issue and investigate, I'm only guessing at the moment what the issue *could* be.

Comment: Yes, i've readed that comment, but it's not my case, i'm not altering the dom tree in my loop, so this does not apply for me. You have voted negative to my question, but i've made A LOT of researching until i finally asked here...

Comment: I wasn't the one who voted your question down (I don't even have enough reputation points to do it, and even if I had I wouldn't downvote it). I just was wondering why it was downvoted since it's actually a question worth getting an answer to. I'm still looking into it right now and trying to replicate the behavior.